# stock management for partial shipment in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am currently working on a project relating to a stock management system on laravel 5.6. Basically I have 3 tables in a MySQL database that I will link to my program; **parts, order and receive**

**Parts** table looks like

```
id  | brand    |  model    |   partcode    |  partname
1   | Apple    |  Iphone X |    ixmainpcb  |    PCB  
2   | Apple    |  Iphone X |    ixLCD      |   Main PCB 
3   | Apple    |  Iphone X |    ixcamera   |   PCB
```

**Order** table looks like

```
id  |part_id | orderno | orderqty | freeqty | purchaseqty | price | totalqty
1   |   1    |  O18001 |    1000  |    50   |     950     |  9500 |   1000
2   |   2    |  O18002 |    1500  |   100   |     1400    | 28000 |   1500
3   |   3    |  O18003 |    2000  |   100   |     1900    | 38000 |   2000
```

we have to pay price for the purchaseqty only no need to pay for the freeqty. freeqty is the scheme quantity. price is the total price amount.

**Receive** looks like

```
id  | order_id |fresh | defect | short | excess | Stock | totalreceive
1   |    1     | 600  |   100  |  300  |   0    |    5  |    700
2   |    2     | 400  |   50   |  1050 |   0    |   130 |    450
3   |    1     | 300  |   0    |   0   |   0    |   300 |    300
```

At first shipment **order_id 1** product is received 700 pieces. It was sold to the customer and now in stock I have only 5 pieces left. At the second shipment my **order_id 1** shipment has been completed by receiving the 300 pieces, so **defect and short would be 0** in table and **stock** field will be 300 for third row.

> **While selling the actual problem arises.**
>
> What can I do in the following cases.
>
> Case 1:

Suppose the customer want to buy 50 pieces product which have order_id 1. Then when I sell it the 5 should be deducted from first row and remaining 45 should be deducted from third row so that my new receive table would look like

```
id  | order_id |fresh | defect | short | excess | Stock | totalreceive
1   |    1     | 600  |   100  |  300  |   0    |    0  |    700
2   |    2     | 400  |   50   |  1050 |   0    |   130 |    450
3   |    1     | 300  |   0    |   0   |   0    |   255 |    300
```

> Case 2:

Suppose the customer want to buy 5 (or less than 5) pieces product which have order_id 1. Then when I sell it from the first row so that my new receive table would look like

```
id  | order_id |fresh | defect | short | excess | Stock | totalreceive
1   |    1     | 600  |   100  |  300  |   0    |    0  |    700
2   |    2     | 400  |   50   |  1050 |   0    |   130 |    450
3   |    1     | 300  |   0    |   0   |   0    |   300 |    300
```

**What is the best way\logic to handle these cases. Thanks in advance.**

Here is the code of what I have done to store the selling data in database.
I don't know whether this logic is correct or not. Any help would be appreciated.

I have passed this value from view using ajax to controller.

```
$deps  = Input::only('id', 'vpoid', 'issueqty', 'vpostock', 'amount', 'discount', 'vat', 'netamount', 'status', 'remarks');

    $id =$deps['id'];
    $vpoid = $deps['vpoid'];
    $issueqty = $deps['issueqty'];
    $vpostock = $deps['vpostock'];
    $amount = $deps['amount'];
    $discount = $deps['discount'];
    $vat = $deps['vat'];
    $netamount = $deps['netamount'];
    $status = $deps['status'];
    $remarks = $deps['remarks'];


    $newstock = 0;
    foreach ($vpoid as $key => $n) {
        //For Updating the stock in receive table
        $chk = VpoUpload::where("id", "=", $vpoid[$key])->get();
        $newstock = ((int)$chk[0]->stockqty) - $issueqty[$key];
        DB::table('vpo')->where("id", "=", $vpoid[$key])->update(array(
            'stockqty' => $newstock,
            )
        );
    }


 for ($i=0; $i < count($receiveqty); $i++) { 
        $data[] =[
            'receiveqty' =>$issueqty[$i],
            'amount' => $amount[$i],
            'status' => $status[$i],
            'remarks' => $remarks[$i],
        ];
    }

    $vpouploads = VpoSell::insert($data);
```

Comment: You tried anything?

Comment: Yeah I have tried. But it doesn't give me the desird answer as i mentioned above in question.

Comment: Then you should paste your query also.

Comment: I thought My question would look big so I didn't. Do you want me to post what I have tried too.

Comment: Do not worry about the question being big. Your question should be clear enough for readers to understand the issue.